# Can not read any text file

Tags: java, android, file-io

First of all, I would like you to say that I am quite new here and I'm also a beginner in Android Studio and Java.

My problem/question is:
I have an App in Android Studio which should write a string to a text file at a specific point and also should read the same file on App startup.

Writing to the file is working but not reading. When I create a text file manually, and insert it manually to the folder it reads the string.

I already added permissions and try to find my error with `LogCat` but I have no clue at the moment what could be wrong.

Variables:

```
File root = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File dir = new File(root.getAbsolutePath() + "/myApp");
```

My reading function:

```
String myData = "";
try {
    FileReader fileIn = new FileReader(dir + "/data.txt");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(fileIn);
    while (input.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = input.nextLine();
        myData = myData + line;
    }
    input.close();

} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

My writing function:

```
try {
    File file = new File(dir, "data.txt");
    FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(file);
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(f);
    pw.println("answer42");
    pw.flush();
    pw.close();
    f.close();
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Two questions. 1) What is 'root' and where are you trying to save this file (a directory private to your app, or a public storage directory)? 2) Have you checked whether an exception is being caught (`ex.printStackTrace()` will print a message to the log)? If so, please add that message to the question.

Comment: What is 'dir' if you write? What is 'root' if you read? Please edit your code so we can see.

Comment: Thank you for your fast answers. I updated the code.

Comment: Sometimes but not evry time i build it i get the following error message: W/System.err: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: getCurrentUser() from pid=2908, uid=10321 requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS